# Deploying a Rails app at heroku with its assets being located at Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make a Rails app server its assets at S3. I'm not using any gems because want to do it manually to better understand the process. My questions regarding serving the **static** assets are:

1. Which assets should I upload to my S3 bucket: from my_app/assets or from  my_app/public/assets?
2. If the second option, it means I have to precompile them first, right? And then  upload the whole folder my_app/public (or my_app/public/assets?) ?
3. Since right now I'm deploying the website at heroku and the max size of the repo at heroku is 300Mb and the size of my assets is much bigger, **how and should I at all** make the app somehow "understand" that its assets are located at S3 so that when I say "git push heroku master" it won't upload all them  from its `my_app/assets` or `my_app/public/ folder`?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the `config.action_controller.asset_host` option on the Rails Configuration. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration

You will indeed need to precompile the assets and sync them to S3. Remember to use `RAILS_ENV=production`. A good place to look at and then replicate manually would be in the [`asset_sync` gem](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync).

Comment: how about my 3rd question?

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear on my answer. When you create or setup a Rails App, the path where the precompiled assets live is ignored by git. Consequently, it will not be pushed to Heroku and your overall repo size should be way below the 300MB. If you want to track large asset files in git, I would recommend taking a look at https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: but the matter is that the folder I'm talking about and which is > 300 Mb is my_app/assets

Comment: Take a look at the Git Large File Storage that I mentioned in my previous comment. People don't usually commit large files to a git repo. By the way, the limit on the repo size at Heroku is 1GB https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#git-repos

Comment: I mean the free heroku account.

Comment: The assets in my_app/assets are not big, but they are big **all together and there're lots of them**.

Comment: Do you need to version control them? If not, simply upload them to S3 and remove them from the repo - https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ can help you on this task.

Comment: I think I do need. Maybe I should them to gitignore? Although, I've never seen anyone did that.

Comment: by the way, why do you think that **When you create or setup a Rails App, the path where the precompiled assets live is ignored by git.** ?